# codeigniter load language add whitespace

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing a multilingual site and using sessions to change language, my issue is when I load a language it is adding a white space on top of page, I tried this ways:

In constructor:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->lang->load('main', $this->session->userdata('language')); 
}
```

[image: top body it adds a white-space]
top body it adds a white-space

When I check in "view source" it does not display any white space but in firebug i can see:
[image]

I also tried to load lang in controller and view but it has same effect.

Edit: I noticed it is only adding space to languages other then English. In English it works fine.

Thanks for any support.

Comment: This solved my issue http://studentguru.gr/b/solidus/archive/2009/12/30/lt-php-include-gt-strange-extra-white-space-at-the-beginning-of-page.aspx

Comment: Why not post that as an answer to your own question? It may help others having a the same issue to find the solution.

Comment: because I could not answer my own question before 24 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was adding a character at top of language file, This solved my issue  http://studentguru.gr/b/solidus/archive/2009/12/30/lt-php-include-gt-strange-extra-white-space-at-the-beginning-of-page.aspx